# How to install difflib module in python 2.7 windows 10

Tags: python-2.7

Currently, I am facing difficulty installing difflib module in python 2.7 version in windows 10 system.

I want it to perform some text analytics analysis

tried using

```
apt-get install npm

npm install difflib
```

and

```
pip.exe install difflib
```

Comment: What is your error message for `pip.exe install difflib`?

Comment: Way i tried installing is "c:\Python27\Scripts>pip install difflib""           
                                                                                               
 Error which am getting is                                                                                                                                       "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement difflib (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for difflib"

Comment: Go to this page to install difflib library.[HERE](https://wholeblogs.com/install-difflib-in-python-using-cmd/) It can help a lot

Answer (score 2):

Solution for me was to save the  [difflib.py](https://github.com/enthought/Python-2.7.3/blob/master/Lib/difflib.py) in the location where your `.py` file resides and then import it in your file.

Answer (score 0):

install using pip should be a great idea, You can refer to the module related details here:

https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/difflib.html

If you face an issue installing it using pip, then the next way is to get the difflib.py from any working machine and keep it in the project directory itself, so that just importing the module itself will work.

This is the codebase reference from svn of python itself:

https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/difflib.py